# 掘り下げなかったであろう in this sentence

Tags: grammar

> A line in a game review contains それら regarding some philosophical
> elements
>
> それらについて深く語られることが無かったのは少し残念ですが、敢えて掘り下げなかったであろうことは、この作品のまとまりを踏まえれば英断と言わざるを得ないでしょう。
>
> It's a bit of a shame that the game didn't go deeper into in the
> philosophical elements, but purposely not delving deeper, if the game
> maintains it's consistency, I have to admit that's a good decision.

- what is であろう adding here?
- The writers has obviously already finished the game, looking for a second opinion if that makes the use of  ば in ...作品のまとまりを踏まえれ**ば** feel a bit awkward. Compare to "作品のまとまりを踏まえるだからこそ英断と言わざるを得ないでしょう" for instance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This であろう is adding the nuance of "presumably" or "seemingly" to 敢えて. それらを掘り下げなかった is an objective fact, but this author is not sure whether that was intentional or unintentional. In other words, he *thinks* they *intentionally* avoided 掘り下げ, but he is not totally sure about that.

踏まえる is a transitive verb meaning "to take ～ into account/consideration".

---

> それらについて深く語られることが無かったのは少し残念ですが、
>   It's a bit of a shame that the game didn't go deeper into in the philosophical elements, but
>
> 敢えて掘り下げなかったであろうことは、
>   (concerning the fact that) their choice of not going into detail **seems to be an intentional one**,...
>
> この作品のまとまりを踏まえれば
>   if I take the work's consistency into consideration, ...
>
> 英断と言わざるを得ないでしょう。
>   I have to admit that's a good decision.