# であろう modifying a noun

Tags: volitional-form

In the book I'm reading I found this part:

> 原因がわからないので、治療もまだ暗中模索の状態であ病気悪くなるのを一時的に止める、あるいは悪くなるスピードを少しゆっきりにする効果のある薬が注目されているが、使われ始めてから日も浅く、長い目で見ていかねばならない。
>
> また、近年の目覚ましい遺伝子工学の発達で、遺伝性の場合には、病気を起こす遺伝子がどの染色体にのっているかを決め、病因となる遺伝子を健常な遺伝子に置き換えることが可能性となるのは時間の問題だが、この時起こる**であろう**遺伝子操作の是非の理論に患者や家族など当事者の悲痛な声が充分に汲み取られることを望みたい

I think であろう is the volitional form of である, but I was unable to understand why it's used there, and while I think I understand the general meaning of the sentence, I don't understand the role であろう plays; I found some answer about であろう, but nothing addressing this Vる + であろう + noun structure.

As far as I understand, the sentence means something like:

> I hope that in the theory of pros and cons of genetic manipulation which are occurring these days, the suffering voice of the people involved, like patients and their families, will be properly taken into account.

As context: the book is １リットルの涙, which is a diary of a girl sick with spinocerebellar degeneration, which caused her to lose all her motor functions as well as her capacity to speak, and in the end killed her. That sentence is part of an afterword writter by her doctor.

Comment: The "modifying a noun" part is simply a relative clause. As for であろう, have you seen this answer? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/64567/30454

Comment: Good catch, @EddieKal. That other thread answers this in better detail.

Comment: @aguijonazo yes, thanks; I was wondering if it made sense to keep this question often for what Nanigashi pointed out in the comments.

Comment: Do you know what [V dictionary form]-であろう means but don’t understand why it comes before a noun?

Comment: I didn't know it could come between a dictionary-form verb and a noun, so I wasn't sure if it added the same meaning of uncertainty to the dictionary-form verb + noun sentence, or if it meant something else.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [掘り下げなかったであろう in this sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/64565/%e6%8e%98%e3%82%8a%e4%b8%8b%e3%81%92%e3%81%aa%e3%81%8b%e3%81%a3%e3%81%9f%e3%81%a7%e3%81%82%e3%82%8d%e3%81%86-in-this-sentence)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

であろう adds a sense of supposition, estimation, or guess: the speaker (or writer) is not certain that this is the case, but is supposing or presuming that it is.

Comment: It appears that Mauro's question mainly concerns the way であろう is being used to modify the noun 理論. This usage does in fact seem to be unusual; in fact, at least one source (https://www.weblio.jp/content/う) even seems to claim that the inferential auxiliary verb う can only modify 形式名詞 like こと (which is how it's used in the example in Eddie Kal's link). I hope you'll consider expanding your answer to address this specific issue!

Comment: @Nanigashi, Mauro's translation suggests that he was not understanding the nuance added by であろう: 「この時起こるであろう遺伝子操作の是非」 → _"pros and cons of genetic manipulation which are occurring these days"_. Rather than _"which are occurring"_, as a flat statement, something more like _"which are p̲r̲o̲b̲a̲b̲l̲y̲ occurring"_ would incorporate the suppositional sense of であろう.

Comment: I confirm that I wasn't understanding those nuances, namely I wasn't aware you could add であろう to have that kind of meaning; but if it's unusual it modifying a noun like 理論 maybe it'd be interesting to keep the question for that too?

Comment: I'm not sure if "*which are probably occurring*" is a correct translation. It sounds more like 起こっているであろう to me.

Comment: Right; it's very clear that @Mauro doesn't understand the nuance added by であろう, but I took the title ("であろう modifying a noun") to mean that this lack of understanding was the result of the specific way であろう is being used in this sentence, rather than of unfamiliarity with the meaning of であろう in general. Of course, I recognize that I may be wrong about that (hence the first three words of my original comment), but either way I think I'm not the only user of the site who would benefit from an analysis of this usage. If you're disinclined to supply one, I hope someone else will.

Comment: Things IRL keeping me busy -- I may be able to revisit this tomorrow.

Comment: @aguijonazo, I agree with you about the tense. It's hard to tell with no context, but I'd take this phrase to mean either "the debates about the pros and cons of genetic manipulation that are likely to occur at that time" (i.e, some particular point in the future that the missing context would make clear) or "the debates about the pros and cons of genetic manipulation that probably occur on such occasions" (with the referent of "such occasions" made clear by whatever context preceded this sentence).

Comment: I understand how volitional, and であろう, can add uncertainty, but I was not familiar with that Vる + であろう + noun construction; if the "modifying noun" isn't relevant, maybe I could change the title to "Vる + であろう + noun construction"? @Nanigashi I added context to the question.

Comment: @Mauro, thanks for clarifying; that's exactly how I interpreted your question, and why I suggested Eiríkr Útlendi consider expanding this answer. As for your title, I think "であろう modifying a noun" is just fine. And thank you for adding some information about where the sentence came from, but it might be even more helpful if you could quote the three or four sentences that precede this one in the book. (In particular, that might help to clarify the meaning of この時 and whether 起こる should be translated as present tense or future tense. As aguijonazo noted, the present continuous seems unlikely.)

Comment: @Nanigashi I added some more lines.

Comment: Thanks, @Mauro! That does clarify that この時 refers to the future -- specifically, the time when it "it will become possible to determine which chromosome carries the gene that gives rise to the disease, and to replace the disease-causing gene with a normal gene." That's about what I expected, but without seeing the context I wasn't completely sure. In general, I think it's a good idea to err on the side of providing more context than you might think necessary when asking about the meaning of a phrase. Ambiguity can make it difficult to pinpoint the source of confusion and write a good answer.